# R move index column to first column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following data frame:

```
              RMSE
A         0.03655830
B         0.24513014
C         0.02009853
D         0.02223135
```

I want to move column that has A,B,C,D to be the first column and add an index to the data.frame.

Answer (score 30):

try this:

```
df <- cbind(newColName = rownames(df), df)
rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(df)
```

hope this is what you meant, the result will be:

```
  newColName       RMSE
1          A 0.03655830
2          B 0.24513014
3          C 0.02009853
4          D 0.02223135
```

Comment: Also `rownames(df) <- NULL`

Comment: @Sotos Doesn't this do the same thing as `rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(df)`?

Comment: @Adam_G Yes. Thats what they have in their answer. I wrote that as an alternative